# How to use Textangular with Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I´m doing the jhipster example (book and author) and I want to use textangular for description fields.
I used this guideline (https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) to do the changes but it does not work.

The question is, if anyone knows a guide to using textangular with jhipster as an example: What files I should modify, how, etc.

I am new at this tried to follow the guide but something is not working.

1. I am doing the JHipster example :http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html
2. I executed Via Bower: bower install textAngular
3. I modified test\src\main\webapp\scripts\app\entities\book\book-detail.html

adding `<div text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable"></div>`

4. I added the 
   script src='/bower_components/textAngular/dist/ explained in the guideline.
5. Currently I tried to do the step 4 explained in the textangular guideline

   a.  Add a dependency to textAngular in your app module, for example: angular.module('myModule', ['textAngular']).

   b.  I tried some option but it does not work.

c.  The current controller file is the following:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('BookDetailController', function ($scope, $stateParams, Book, Author) {
        $scope.book = {};
        $scope.load = function (id) {
            Book.get({id: id}, function(result) {
              $scope.book = result;
            });
        };
        $scope.load($stateParams.id);
    });
```

Could you help me to understand how can I add this line angular.module('myModule', ['textAngular']) without breaking the page, please.

Answer (score 0):

At least you should add to your `bower.json` and run `bower update` afterwards (this should download all required files into your bower_components directory).

Now you add all required files (js, css) to your `index.html` as described in textangular howto. Or do you have a more specific problem?

**EDIT:**

Go to your `app.js` file (`src/main/webapp/app.js`). There you find the module defintion: `angular.module('jhipster', ['LocalStorageModule'...]`. If you named your application different 'jhipster' will be your application name. Just add `'textangular'` at the end of the list of injected modules: e.g:

```
angular.module('jhipster', ['LocalStorageModule','tmh.dynamicLocale','pascalprecht.translate',
'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngCacheBuster', 'infinite-scroll', 'textTangular'])
```